# String Type casting in clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a column named "sessions" in table which looks like this

| session |
| --- |
| [ {"key": "hello", "value": {"string_value": null, "int_value": 1, "float_value": null, "double_value": null}} ] |
| [ {"key": "welocome", "value": {"string_value": "venue", "int_value": null, "float_value": null, "double_value": null}} ] |

when i checked the type of these row values it returns Nullable(String) instead of Array

is there a way to convert these row values to a valid array ? thank you

Comment: How are those strings generated? You might find ClickHouse's [Functions for Working with JSON](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/) helpful. Although JSON uses double rather than single quotes.

Comment: It looks like JSON so you should be able to use something like JSONExtractArrayRaw https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#jsonextractarrayrawjson-indices-or-keys - but maybe you will have issue with the null values